# Apple Id confusion

Tags: apple-id

I just created an Apple ID. Went through the confirmation via email phase successfully.

I am able to log in on this page: https://appleid.apple.com - and under `Apple ID and Primary Email Address` it says it is verified.

However, attempting to reinstall OS X Lion (following a Command - R combo at restart), when I am asked to enter my Apple ID, I get the spinning wheel and then I am being told that `This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store. Please review your account information.` Clicking on the `Review` button doesn't do anything.

Stumped.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a temporary network issue

Comment: @Mark Let's leave this up. There should be a thread covering what happens when the service is down. Even if it's rare, it surely will happen again and pointers to http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ don't always show when a service is having issues..

Comment: @Mark Hi Mark, maybe I wasn't clear. The fact that discussions.apple.com was down has no bearing on the initial issue - I mentioned it only to make it clear that I wasn't even able to Google an answer for my problem. Sorry for the confusion I have created. The machine I was attempting to install OS X on and the one I was using for Internet browsing are on different networks.

Comment: I can deff. see my poor choice of words. I would edit my initial text, but I am afraid this would leave your comments "hanging". Apologies, again.

Comment: No edit the question to make it clear. Comments aren't meant to stay around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my experience there are different levels of appleID approval.

for instance, it can work fine for updates but will need to verify with CC info to use the app store etc.

can you go onto a machine with app store or itunes and 'buy' a free app?  i suspect it will make you enter more info, or verify a CC security id, or something.  after this point, your ID will be blessed for all activities.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. This happens when you have an older OS X version and you never used your account. Some pages of the appstore will not work with some of the older OS X versions. Apple support gave me two ways to fix this:

**Fix 1:**
Login to the appstore with another apple ID that has already been used by you or a friend. Download and install the update. After you have installed the newest OSX version you will be able to login with your own apple ID and everything works again.

**Fix 2:**
Login to the appstore on another device (Mac, iPhone or iPad) which has a newer OSX/iOS version installed. You can use the device of a friend. After you logged in, your account will be updated. Now you can logout on this device and login on your own device.